# Search engine and words with accent doesn't match

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to make a search engine for my site. It works unless there are accents in a word.

For example, if I have the title: "Musée Baudouin", if I write "Musee Baudouin" or "Musée Baudouin", it does not display anything. If I write just "Baudouin", it's work.

I can't find my articles if they have accents in the title.

How to do ?

```
public function searchNav(Request $request)
  {
    $search = $request->get('search');

    $buildings = Building::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->orWhere('city', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->published()->get();
    $events = Event::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->orWhere('city', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->published()->get();

    // Create a new collection and merge elements
    $all = new Collection();
    $all = $all->merge($buildings);
    $all = $all->merge($events);
    $all = $all->sortByDesc('updated_at');
    $this->data['items'] = $all->all();

    return view('pages.search-nav-results', $this->data);
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: This is probably dues to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an encoding problem, meaning that your current encoding does not support accented characters.  Here is a way to create a MySQL database using a UTF-8 encoding, which certainly would support the accented characters in your example:

```
CREATE DATABASE yourdb CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

This would fix the MySQL side of things, assuming you are not already using an encoding which supports those accented characters.  On the PHP side, it is a bit more complicated, but there you also need to make sure that the proper encoding is being supported.  I refer you to a [good blog site](https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql) which covers the PHP details.